# How to execute a method only once if the condition is true and within a particular time period

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Currently I'm developing a C# application where I have to zip a given folder and then upload that zipped file to a given url (server). For this I've created two methods to create the zip file (CreateZipFile) and then to upload (UploadZipFile)it.

These two methods can be called by different users(different threads)concurrently. Before executing the CreateZipFile method I need to check whether that folder which threads are requesting to be zipped is same, if so I need to execute the method only once with in 1 minute time interval(Since the folder is not updating during 1 minute time period don't need to create multiple zip files for the same folder). However if threads are requesting different folders to be zipped then I need to create zip files for each of those folder.

This is the CreateZipFile method I've implemented

```
private static string CreateZipFile(string sourceDirPath)
    {
        string zipFileName = "";
        try
        {
            // Construct the zip file name
            zipFileName = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirPath).Name + ".zip";

            if (File.Exists(zipFileName))
            {
                File.Delete(zipFileName);
            }

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourceDirPath, zipFileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("CreateZipDirectory", ex);
        }

        return zipFileName;
    }
```

This is the UploadZipFile method I've implemented

```
private bool UploadZipFile(string sourceFilePath, string destinationUrl)
    {
        bool status = false;

        for (int retryAttempt = 1; retryAttempt <= MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS; retryAttempt++)
        {
            try
            {
                string fileNameWOExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFilePath);
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StreamContent(File.Open(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open)), fileNameWOExt, sourceFilePath);
                var result = client.PostAsync(destinationUrl, content);

                if ((Int32)result.Result.StatusCode == 200)
                {
                    status = true;
                    logger.Info("UploadLogDirectory", "Log directory uploaded successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Info("UploadLogDirectory", "Upload Error: Status " + (Int32)result.Result.StatusCode);
                }

                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(ex is AggregateException)
                {
                    if (retryAttempt <= MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
        }

        return status;
    }
```

This is how I call these methods

```
private void ExportLogDirectory(TaskBase taskObj)
    {
        bool status = false;
        try
        {
            string directoryPath = taskObj.GetParam("DirectoryPath").GetValue();
            string destinationUrl = taskObj.GetParam("destinationUrl").GetValue();

            // Zip the log directory
            string createdZipFile = CreateZipFile(directoryPath);


            // Upload the zipped log directory
            status = UploadZipFile(createdZipFile, destinationUrl);

            if(status)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FAIL")
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("ExportLogDirectory", ex);
        }
```

I need to know is how to check whether the folders that each threads are requesting to zip are same or not before executing the CreateZipFile method ? If I can obtain this then I can synchronize the method or lock it according to that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should track when a folder was last zipped and make a decision on that basis.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> zipTimes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>();
```

In your CreateZipFile(), add the following lines in try block at start.

```
DateTime updatedTime;
if( zipTimes.TryGetValue( sourceDirPath, out updatedTime ) && ( DateTime.Now - updatedTime ).TotalMinutes < 1 )
    return;
zipTimes [ sourceDirPath ] = DateTime.Now;
```